# Layout fix with images rendered via dynamic image handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, image-scaling

I am using a httphandler to dynamically resize images that are rendered on a page.  I have a preset width that all images must confirm - and the height of the images can vary (proportions constrained to the original width and height).  I am caching the images - however, when they are originally loaded, the httphandler is called after the page is rendered - so for longer images - sometimes on intial load, layout breaks with larger images as they overlap the content that is below it. Here is an example screenshot from here http://www.teakmonkeystudios.ca/photos/photo.aspx?id=10801:

[image]

Here is the css:

```
.gallery
{

    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:5px;
}


ul.gallery div.top_frame
{
       width:732px
}


ul.gallery div.view_frame
{
    margin-left:5px;
}

ul.gallery div.image_frame
{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding-top: 5px; height:100%; min-height:490px;
    padding-bottom: 5px; text-align: center;
}

ul.gallery div.button_frame
{
    width: 732px; text-align: right; margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}


ul.gallery div.name_frame, ul.gallery div.original_name_frame
{

    margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

ul.gallery div.name_frame h2
{
    margin: 2px 0px 3px 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

ul.gallery div.date_frame
{
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

ul.gallery div.update_frame
{
    width: 732px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-align:right;
}



ul.gallery div.desc_frame
{
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;

}

ul.gallery li
{
     width: 732px;

     display: -moz-inline-stack;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align:top;
     margin: 5px;
     zoom: 1;
     *display: inline;
     _height:100%;
      color:#000000;
      letter-spacing:0px;
      line-height:normal;

} 

ul.breadcrumbs li
{
    float:left;

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}

ul.breadcrumbs li a
{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Since the image in the screenshot below may be cached you may not see the broken layout.  I wonder if rendering the images in a table would be better?  Or is there a css fix?  I've even tried Jquery and used document ready to adjust the height of the image containers - but the image may not be loaded - so I can't return the height of the image in the function.  Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason [you're reinventing the wheel](http://imageresizing.net)?

Answer (score 0):

If your images are all going to be the same width, output the IMG tag with a width attribute. this may help.

```
<img src="..." width="720">
```

Using `input type="image"` for this type of application is a bit odd. Why not just use an A-tag wrapped around an image?

Comment: I will try using the width attribute.  I was also thinking about wrapping an image in a hyperlink.  I used an image button for this instance cause I wanted to execute code on a click event.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effects of masking the problem, increasing web site traffic by sending a large image where a smaller one might be enough and allowing the web browser to do the resizing. It's not a solution, it is, at most, a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

This is the key to your problem:

> however, when they are originally loaded, the httphandler is called after the page is rendered

An [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) sees the request before the response is sent to the browser and can do whatever it needs, including responding with a resized image. I'm doing that a lot, never had a problem. Since it doesn't work for you, I'm 100% you've got a bug in your HttpHandler.

Comment: If I am using a dynamic image custom control that renders a string to the browser - which calls the httphandler to process the image based on the information it pulls from the string.  That request (for the dynamic image) will not be called until the string is rendered to the browser.  Am I incorrect here?

Comment: It doesn't really matter how the browser gets it's markup. At some point it needs to request an image from the server using a URL. The IHttpHandler intercepts that request and can do things to it before standard processing is done. But I don't think this is your problem. I followed the link to your site and the greenish element that's shown in here misplaced is an DIV, doesn't contain any kind of image whatsoever, not even as a CSS background image! Can you point me to the name of the image that isn't properly resized? Give me it's `ID`

Comment: Rethinking this - you mentioned you have used dynamic images frequently and haven't seen this problem.  In my custom control a string is rendered as the image url: src="../controls/cachedimageservice.axd?data=db_10801_h720_w720_t0 - and that request is then intercepted by the handler and checks the cache (or creates the image if not found in the cache).  If I create the cached image first in the prerender method of my custom control - I don't seem to run into this problem.  I'm assuming you cache your images when they are created dynamically - where in the pipeline are you calling for them?

Comment: IHttpHandler only offers one place to process the request, there's no choice: you do it in ProcessRequest. Unless you're calling something else a HttpHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If i create the image and load it into the cache in the custom image's prerender event - it seems to have fixed this issue.  Originally the control rendered the image info to the src string in the browser and the image was then intercepted by a httphandler that calls a cachemanager (if exists  - return, if not - create).  Since the problem above seemed to happen only when the image was initially created - I figured recreating it before it was 'requested' may help - and it appears it has.  If there are consequences to this - I will edit my solution.

Comment: Creating the image in the pre render event improved the situation but wasn't the fix - as under testing I still saw the broken layout like above. I think this really is a css problem and I'm rendering the image in a table now. If this fixes the issue I'll post back.